# How to design a powerpoint slide and convert it into web page?

Tags: html, microsoft-powerpoint

Is there any website, tool, software to convert a powerpoint or word page to a html web page

Comment: Please tell us what have you done so far to find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

yes here is a web apliction who does this :

first step convert your PowerPoint slide to word document then use this web application to convert the word to HTML , I hope this sweets your needs !

**[Link](http://word2cleanhtml.com/)**

and if you are familiar with c# you can find many codes who do this for you